# How to check two conditions in mysql sum

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select cust_code,occu_name
, SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'S' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS salesSum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'I' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS interestSum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = '' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS interest_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'P' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS chequereturn_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'R' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS receipt_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'R' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS receipt_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'N' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS credit_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN (DrCrType = 'DR' and VoucherDate <= '2012-04-01') THEN Amount ELSE (Amount*-1)) AS opening_sum
from bmwregistration, ledger_transactions
where bmwregistration.ledger_id = ledger_transactions.OccupierID and
  VoucherDate >= '2012-04-01' and
  VoucherDate <= '2013-02-01'
group by cust_code
```

How to check two conditions in sum function `SUM(CASE WHEN (DrCrType = 'DR' and VoucherDate <= '2012-04-01') THEN Amount ELSE (Amount*-1)) AS opening_sum`

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes it is not right syntax

Comment: I need to subtract amount in that clause

Comment: multiply by -1 to amount

Comment: Sorry problem with query observe dates VoucherDate <= '2012-04-01' in sum and VoucherDate >= '2012-04-01' in where clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it in correct way.

#### [See this Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ad53/2)

You just did a little mistake. All you need is to add `END` after that conditions like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DrCrType = 'DR' 
          and VoucherDate <= '2012-04-01' 
         THEN Amount 
         ELSE (Amount*-1) END) AS opening_sum
                          ^^^
```

So your whole query should be like this:

```
select cust_code,occu_name
, SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'S' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS salesSum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'I' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS interestSum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = '' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS interest_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'P' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS chequereturn_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'R' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS receipt_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'R' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS receipt_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN VoucherType = 'N' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS credit_sum
SUM(CASE WHEN DrCrType = 'DR' 
          and VoucherDate <= '2012-04-01' 
         THEN Amount 
         ELSE (Amount*-1) END) AS opening_sum
from bmwregistration, ledger_transactions
where bmwregistration.ledger_id = ledger_transactions.OccupierID and
  VoucherDate >= '2012-04-01' and
  VoucherDate <= '2013-02-01'
group by cust_code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 WHEN PAT_DrCrType = 'DR' and VoucherDate <= '2012-04-01' THEN Amount ELSE (Amount-1)) AS opening_sum
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DrCrType = 'DR' AND VoucherDate <= '2012-04-01' THEN Amount ELSE (Amount-1) END)
```